# Скрипт поиска каналов Ютуб

Tags: python, парсер, api, youtube

Вот код:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Установка ключа API и создание экземпляра объекта youtube
api_key = "***"
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

# Функция для поиска каналов
def search_channels(query, min_subscriber_count=0, published_after=None):
    # Определение параметров запроса
    query_params = {
        'q': query,
        'type': 'channel',
        'part': 'id,snippet',
        'maxResults': 10,
        'order': 'relevance'
    }
    # Добавление параметров фильтрации
    if min_subscriber_count > 0:
        query_params['minSubscriberCount'] = min_subscriber_count

    if published_after is not None:
        query_params['publishedAfter'] = published_after
    # Выполнение запроса
    request = youtube.search().list(**query_params)
    response = request.execute()
    channels = []
    # Обработка результатов
    for item in response['items']:
        channel = {
            'id': item['id']['channelId'],
            'title': item['snippet']['title'],
            'description': item['snippet']['description'],
            'published_at': item['snippet']['publishedAt'],
            'thumbnail': item['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'],
            'subscriber_count': 0
        }
        # Получение информации о количестве подписчиков
        statistics = youtube.channels().list(
            part='statistics',
            id=channel['id']
        ).execute()
        if statistics['items']:
            channel['subscriber_count'] = int(statistics['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'])
        channels.append(channel)
    return channels

# Пример использования функции search_channels
six_months_ago = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=180)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
channels = search_channels('python', min_subscriber_count=50000, published_after=six_months_ago)
for channel in channels:
    print(f"{channel['title']} ({channel['subscriber_count']} подписчиков)")
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\Puzyrin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 1048, in method
    raise TypeError("Got an unexpected keyword argument {}".format(name))
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument minSubscriberCount
```

Помогите пожалуйста с именами в апи.

Comment: Заходим в [документацию](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=ru) к этому методу и видим, что у него нет параметра `minSubscriberCount`. Так что фильтруйте *ручками*

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Установка ключа API и создание экземпляра объекта youtube
api_key = "***"  # Замените на свой API ключ
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

# Функция для поиска каналов по названию
def search_channels_by_title(query, min_subscriber_count=0, published_after=None):
    # Определение параметров запроса
    query_params = {
        'q': query,  # Поиск по названию
        'type': 'channel',
        'part': 'id,snippet',
        'maxResults': 10,
        'order': 'relevance'
    }
    # Добавление параметров фильтрации
    if min_subscriber_count > 0:
        query_params['minSubscriberCount'] = min_subscriber_count

    if published_after is not None:
        query_params['publishedAfter'] = published_after
    # Выполнение запроса
    request = youtube.search().list(**query_params)
    response = request.execute()
    channels = []
    # Обработка результатов
    for item in response['items']:
        channel = {
            'id': item['id']['channelId'],
            'title': item['snippet']['title'],
            'description': item['snippet']['description'],
            'published_at': item['snippet']['publishedAt'],
            'thumbnail': item['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'],
            'subscriber_count': 0
        }
        # Получение информации о количестве подписчиков
        statistics = youtube.channels().list(
            part='statistics',
            id=channel['id']
        ).execute()
        if statistics['items']:
            channel['subscriber_count'] = int(statistics['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'])
        channels.append(channel)
    return channels

# Пример использования функции search_channels_by_title
six_months_ago = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=180)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
channels = search_channels_by_title('Название канала', min_subscriber_count=50000, published_after=six_months_ago)
for channel in channels:
    print(f"{channel['title']} ({channel['subscriber_count']} подписчиков)")
```